# Page identicator and android

Tags: android

I want to do some like this:
[image]

I want to do some like on this picture. I want to change photos na have this small circles. Is in android any widget to do that?
How I can do this?

Comment: Check this project on GitHub - [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a GalleryView along with a RadioGroup where each dot is a RadioButton, then you can change the radio selected when the GalleryView is changed.

You can also style the dots and make them look whatever you want.